# Parse multiple arrays in json from file using Lua

Tags: arrays, json, lua

Using SSLLABS-SCAN for auditing ssl on various websites this outputs a single .json formatted file with an array for each host.

I'm using a Lua json module to decode the contents of the .json file. 
I can read the file and print it but cannot get the parsing to work. It should be easy enough, I've tried both json and cjson as a module to no avail.

`urls.json` is where the whole output ends up for all hosts which were scanned

[ json-data for host 1 { "key" : "value" , "key" : "value" .... } ]
[ json-data for host n { "key" : "value" , "key" : "value" .... } ]

I've checked and the .json file is correctly formatted.

I've thrown away all previous code and started over. Noting when I read the file it is formatted as a string, xfile only seems to receive a single k,v pair.

---

```
local cjson = require "cjson"
local json = require "json"

io.input("urls.json")
file = io.read("*all")
-- the below prints file = string
    print ("file  = ",type(file))
-- init the table named xfile
xfile = {}
xfile = json.decode(file)
-- the below prints xfile = table
print ("xfile = ", type(xfile))

-- the below prints i=1
for i=1,#xfile do
    print ("i=",i)
end
-- the below prints 1 table: 0x987230
for k,v in pairs(xfile) do
    print (k,v)
end
io.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide a test case, some JSON,  where it fails?

Comment: hi, it does not really fail. It's just not doing anything. I've parsed the json file with jsonpipe and json2lua which work fine.
  
No sample JSON for now, it is output from https://github.com/ssllabs/ssllabs-scan 
  
Take note NOT to use -json-flat=true for output since it does not parse with the existing lua modules

Comment: check [this link](http://hastebin.com/liqubetela.tex) for sample json data

Comment: What about that comment-explained output is confusing? That's exactly what I would expect for that linked input. Have you tried seeing what's in that `v` table? I expect it to be the data for the host so it should have 'host', 'port', etc. keys.

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry, your comment is not making much sense. I'm trying to import the .json file in a decoded way into a lua table. This is not working at this time.

Comment: You say it isn't working but you haven't shown it not working. You documented the code snippet with what I assume are the output you are getting when you run it, right? That output shows that you ended at a table value. Did you inspect that table value? It should have what you want in it.

Comment: @EtanReisner AFAIK that is what the last for ... end is about

Comment: The `for k,v in pairs(xfile) do ... end` loop *only* loops over `xfile`. It then prints out that `v` is a table. You don't print *that* table. You need to. There's more data available in `xfile` then you've printed. There are various options available on the [TableSerialization](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) lua-users wiki page that might be of use to you here.

Comment: @SaintCrusty 
According to the sample json, you are getting a anonymous array(table) with one key (index =1) and the whole json content in the value. 
Seems to be that's working as expected, just use 
`local json_data = xfile[1] or {}
print("First entry hostname: ", tostring(json_data["host"]))
`
output: First entry hostname:  stackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks people, i'll work with that for now. Amazingly this is not documented on either the cjson or json documentation pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the whole decoded json data in on the 'value' element of the first key in your xfile table:

Using the [sample file](http://hastebin.com/liqubetela.tex):

```
...    
local json_data = xfile[1] or {} 
print("First entry hostname: ", tostring(json_data["host"]))
```

output:

> First entry hostname: stackoverflow.com

Comment: This might be just what i need since the json contians much more than what i need

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. It may be worth noting this json is nested. Adressing a nested element can be done as for example json_data["endpoints"][1]["ipAddress"] , to get to an easy view on this tree use jsonpipe and replace /0/ with [1] for use with lua tables.

Comment: It's working well with what i've learned. What is left is to find out how to work with the tables in tables in tables and how to detect this from the script instead of working out the structure.